# putting a foreach inside foreach

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop some array using `foreach`.
This is the code which demonstrates what I'm doing:

```
 $arr1=array("32,45,67,89");
    $arr2=array("5,3,2,1");

    foreach($arr1 as $key => $val){
      foreach($arr2 as $key2 =>$val2){
         echo $val."-".$key2."-".$val2;
        }
}
```

However, this outputs

> 32-0-5
>
> 32-1-3
>
> 32-2-2
>
> 32-3-1

and I want to display it like this instead

> > 32-1-5
> >
> > 45-2-3
> >
> > 67-3-2
> >
> > 89-3-1

How can I solve this? Since I'm a beginner I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't want to loop over the 2nd array, you just want to get the value at a certain position.  Try it like this:

```
foreach($arr1 as $key => $val){
  $val2 = $arr2[$key];
  echo $val."-".($key+1)."-".$val2;
}
```

Comment: how to prevent duplicate? should i put break in first foreach?

Comment: You're welcome.  You only need one `foreach`, and `break;` stops the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're doing a double foreach because you actually want to print 4*4 = 16 rows. I also assume that you mistyped the last row, where you have a 3 instead of a 4.

Just using ($key2+1) can be enough for you ?

```
$arr1=array("32,45,67,89");
$arr2=array("5,3,2,1");

foreach($arr1 as $key => $val){
  foreach($arr2 as $key2 =>$val2){
     echo $val."-" . ($key2+1) . "-".$val2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not nest the loops;

Use one loop and print array1[i]."-".array2[i]

Comment: can you give me some example sir?

Comment: I don't know PHP; I can help only with concepts

Comment: its ok sir Rocket got the idea and thank you for you kind reply

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop instead of foreach too:

```
$arr1=array(32,45,67,89);
$arr2=array(5,3,2,1);    
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    echo $arr1[$i] . "-" . ($i+1) . "-" . $arr2[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$i<count ($arr1)` counts the number of elements in the array.
And then stop once it gets to the end.

If you have the name number of elements in each array. This would be great for you or even to create tables dynamically.

```
$arr1=array("32,45,67,89");
$arr2=array("5,3,2,1");

for ($i=0; $i<count ($arr1) ; $i++){
echo $arr1[$i] . "-" . $arr1[$i]."-". $arr2[$i] ;

}
```